# how to assign jquery function to css stylesheet

Tags: jquery

How can I assign a jquery function in my css stylesheet? For eg. I have the following css

```
div{width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: red;}
```

Is this the way?

```
div{width: $func_width; height: $func_height; background-color: $func_color;}
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Sorry.

Comment: use SASS [Sass is an extension of CSS that adds power and elegance to the basic language]

Comment: You need to do this in javascript, javascript is for javascript and css is for css only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can't. Better you try [jquery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('div').css({'width':$func_width,'height': $func_height,'background-color': $func_color});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. But you can assign those function as a css property dynamically to HTML elements with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').css({'width':$func_width,'height': $func_height,'background-color': $func_color});


 // of you can use
 $('div').css('width' , $func_width);
 $('div').css('height' , $func_heigh);
});
```

Hope it will help